# Laravel pass list parameters (columns) in select query

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, parameter-passing, yajra-datatable

I use three table **spareparts**, **categories** and **parameter** and YajraDatatables.

My controller action is:

```
    public function anyData()
    {
        $spareparts_param_list = Sparepart::all();
        $list='';
        foreach ($spareparts_param_list as $value) {
            foreach ($value->category->parameter as $par_list) {
                $list .=  $par_list->Name.',';
            }
        }
        $spareparts = Sparepart::
            join('cars', 'spareparts.car_id', '=', 'cars.id')
            ->select(['spareparts.id', 'cars.Brend', 'spareparts.Model', $list]);
        $datatables = app('datatables')->of($spareparts);

        return $datatables->make();
    }
```

My array list **$list** print parameters such as *color,type,tires,*.
How to pass **$list** array in select query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereIn`:

```
public function anyData()
{
    $spareparts_param_list = Sparepart::all();
    $list = [];
    foreach ($spareparts_param_list as $value) {
        foreach ($value->category->parameter as $par_list) {
            $list[] = $par_list->Name;
        }
    }
    $spareparts = Sparepart::
        join('cars', 'spareparts.car_id', '=', 'cars.id')
        ->whereIn('Name', $list)
        ->select(['spareparts.id', 'cars.Brend', 'spareparts.Model']);
    $datatables = app('datatables')->of($spareparts);

    return $datatables->make();
}
```

You can run this raw `Mysql` command:

```
select sp.id as sp_id, sp.model as sp_model, c.brend as car_brend, json_arrayagg(p.name) as p_name
from spareparts as sp
join cars as c on sp.car_id=c.id
join categories as cat on sp.category_id=cat.id
join parameters as p on cat.id=p.category_id
group by sp.model;
```

Above command will give you a result like the following:

`1 | Audi A6 door | Audi A6 | ["color", "window"]`

The last column will be a json column of all parameters related to each category.

Comment: This is okay. However, each of the parts has its own category which has it own parameters . For example,  part **Audi A6 door** (table spareparts) have category door (table categories) and door have parameters (table parameters) like as _window,color,etc._. The names of these parameters are added to the spareparts table as columns and I would like the names of these parameters to be show in select query through $list variable

Comment: I added a raw Mysql query, please check it. @dbudimir

Answer (score 1):

You can use **whereIn()**, something like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                ->get();
```

Docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses